# How to decompress .tgz files in java

Tags: java, algorithm, archive

I want to know, how to decompress `.tgz` file  to `.tar` using apache commons. As i am able to extract the .tar file but for `.tgz` file first i need to bring it to .tar which I seems to be an issue for me.
`.tgz` file is something which i need to unzip it first so that .tar will be available. However, zip extraction is not working on `.tgz` file for me.

My main concern is , how to decompress `.tgz` file to `.tar`.

any suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Apache Commons for `.tgz` to `tar`. That's because `.tgz` is `.tar` with GZIP compression applied. Create an `InputStream` for the file, wrap it in a `GZIPInputStream`, and read from that. You can use that directly in creating a `TarArchiveInputStream` if you want:

```
try (InputStream source = Files.newInputStream(file);
        GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(source);
        TarArchiveInputStream tar = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzip)) {

    TarArchiveEntry entry;
    while ((entry = tar.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
        // do somthing with entry
    }
}
```